# How to disable TLS 1.0 in Wildfly swarm

Tags: ssl, wildfly, wildfly-swarm

Just found out that in Wildfly Swarm 2018.5.0, we can't manage to disable the older TLSv1.0 and TLSv1.1 protocols.

We used to do it like below in 2017.x;

```
-Dswarm.undertow.servers.default-server.https-listeners.https.enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"
```

However, now, this gives me an weird message without much explanation.

```
INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 4) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.1.6.Final
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 8) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "undertow"),
("server" => "default-server"),
("https-listener" => "https")
]) - failure description: "WFLYCTL0155: 'socket-binding' may not be null"
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) "WFLYCTL0193: Failed executing subsystem undertow boot operations"
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("parallel-subsystem-boot") failed - address: ([]) - failure description: "\"WFLYCTL0193: Failed executing subsystem undertow boot operations\""
FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure in which 2017.x version this used to work for you, because this "issue" is caused by this line: https://github.com/thorntail/thorntail/blob/2.5.0.Final/fractions/javaee/undertow/src/main/java/org/wildfly/swarm/undertow/runtime/HTTPSCustomizer.java#L78 And that's been there for quite a while.

Basically, if you don't configure any HTTPS listener, default one (called `default-https`) will be created automatically. But you do configure one (called `https`), so default configuration doesn't happen. You need to provide at least the two properties configured in the `HTTPSCustomizer` as shown above. That is:

```
-Dswarm.undertow.servers.default-server.https-listeners.https.security-realm=SSLRealm
-Dswarm.undertow.servers.default-server.https-listeners.https.socket-binding=https
-Dswarm.undertow.servers.default-server.https-listeners.https.enabled-protocols="TLSv1.2"
```